# How to get below result

Tags: sql-server

I have below given table

```
ID  Value  
1   10  
2   20  
3   40
```

I want below output

```
ID  Value Total    
1   10    10  
2   20    30  
3   40    70
```

I want to calculate total by adding value in each column by adding total column in result.

Comment: Just google running total?

Comment: This will [help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server) you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    id
  , value
  , SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Total
FROM YourTable
```